# How to resize image (editing css)

Tags: css

I am trying to edit a wordpress template. My goal is to make movie posters look bigger than now.

This is how it looks at the moment - http://prntscr.com/i30lgt

This is how it looks when i edint height in the css - http://prntscr.com/i30ltf

The changes i made are in this css code:

```
  .loop-container article img.attachment-post-thumbnail {
width: 100%;
height: 450px;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.175s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.175s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.175s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.175s ease-in-out; }
```

How can i make them resize properly and not stretch?

Comment: Hello, 
You won't be able to keep the same ratio by editing the height.
You could try `transform: scale(1.2);`

Comment: Provide code, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you

```
    <div class="article">
            <img alt="img" src="thumb-image.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail">
    </div>
    <style>

    .article{
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
        height:450px;
    }

    .article img.attachment-post-thumbnail {
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
        display:block;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit:cover;` if you want your image to cover the div or whatever.
Or, make `height:auto`.

`object-fit:cover;` will crop your image from two sides.